# Aplicar CSS usando 'class' dos elementos (JS)

Tags: javascript, css3

**[APENAS PARA ESTUDO]**

Ao clicar em um botão, eu preciso fazer com que a função aplique um width nos elementos com a classe **"border_title_result"**.

```
function spanSize(){
                var div = document.getElementById('title_result');
                var size = 700 - div.offsetWidth;
                var f = size + "px";
                console.log(f);

                document.getElementsByClassName('border_title_result').style.width = f;
            }
```

O **width** é definido conforme o tamanho de uma div - 700px;

Eu já testei usando **'getElementById'** para apenas um elemento, porém não sei como eu consigo aplicar esse mesmo css em vários elementos.

Os elementos são dinamicos, eles são escritos usando **PHP**, por isso não posso simplesmente fazer uma variavel para cada elemento **id**.

**Isso é puramente para ESTUDO**, quero apenas aprender a plicar **js** usando **class**.

Comment: John, dá uma olhada na duplicada, o princípio é o mesmo. Tem que usar `for` para percorrer os elementos pela classe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso você pode contar com o jQuery

> https://jquery.com/

Com ele você poderia fazer simplesmente

```
$('.border_title_result').each(function (){
     this.css('width', f)
})
```

Agora se realmente deseja utilizar JS puro tente:

```
function spanSize() {
    var div = document.getElementById('title_result');
    var size = 700 - div.offsetWidth;
    var f = size + "px";
    console.log(f);

    var borderTitleResults = document.querySelectorAll(".border_title_result")

    for (i = 0; i < borderTitleResults.length; i++) {
        borderTitleResults[i].style.width = f;
    }

    //ES6
    borderTitleResults.map(i => i.style.width = f)
}
```